# Record data moving to New Line

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have CSV file in which few records the data is moving to New line:

Example:

```
  ABCD,1234,QWER
  ASDF
  ,2345,VGFT
  "ASDF,12",1212,ASDR 
  1234,ZXCV,ERTT
```

the output result should be:

```
  ABCD,1234,QWER
  ASDF,2345,VGFT
 "ASDF,12",1212,ASDR 
  1234,ZXCV,ERTT
```

Is there a way I can concatenate 2nd and 3rd column?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include one more scenario "ASDF,12",1212,ASDR

Comment: You should edit the question to include the scenario; the addition may get overlooked in the comment section.

Comment: That file is broken, if the contents are important (like if the wrong thing happens you might have to talk to a judge) send it back and ask for a replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a mix of shell variables we can do it in GNU `sed` as shown:

```
nF='[^,]*';        # a normal unquoted csv field
qF='"[^"]*"';      # a quoted csv field
F="\($qF\|$nF\)";  # a csv field
ok="$F,$F,$F\$";   # a csv record with exactly 3 fields
# ok="\($F,\)\{2\}$F\$"; # an equivalent way to write out the regex for an ok csv record

sed -e "
    :a;/$ok/b       
    N;s/\n//;ba
" input.csv
```

outputs

```
ABCD,1234,QWER
ASDF,2345,VGFT
"ASDF,12",1212,ASDR 
1234,ZXCV,ERTT
```

works as

- Build the grammar of a csv using a mix of shell variables to be used in sed.
- Assuming that a csv record has no more than 3 fields.
- First check if the csv record is ok, meaning, it has exactly 3 fields. In that case, just print the record and read the next record.
- OTW, meaning, less than 3 fields were found in the current csv record, we append the next line by means of the `N` command, then remove the connector, a `\n`, and with this modified pattern space, branch to the top of the sed code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive hack that works on the data given:

```
$ awk -F, 'NF != 3 { printf("%s",$0); getline } 1' file.csv
ABCD,1234,QWER
ASDF,2345,VGFT
1234,ZXCV,ERTT
```

What it does is using `awk` to parse the file as a comma-delimited dataset.  If a line does not have exactly three fields (`NF != 3`), then the bit of the line that has been read so far is outputted as is with no trailing newline and the next line is read.  The final `1` is short for `{ print }` and will print all lines.

If the first block has triggered, then that final `1`/`print` will cause the remainder of the broken line to be outputted at the end of what was outputted by `printf`.

A variation of this with `sed`:

```
$ sed -E '/^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$/!{ N; s/\n//; }' file.csv
ABCD,1234,QWER
ASDF,2345,VGFT
1234,ZXCV,ERTT
```

Again, this may not work if the lines are broken in other ways than what's shown in the example data.

What the `sed` script does is to test each line with the regular expression `^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$`.  If this matches, we have a line that looks like it ought to do; three fields consisting of characters other than commas, delimited by commas.  If that is *not* the case, the next line is appended to the end of the current line with `N`, and the newline that `sed` inserts between the two is removed.

The `sed` code follows the same logic as the `awk` code in that it appends the next line of data if the current line is faulty.

Comment: sed -E '/^[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+$/!{ N; s/\n//; }' file.csv this command worked thank you , I have 26 delimiters so should I include  ,[^,] 26 times or is there other way to do it like wiring a script

Comment: @Yarlly You should be able to use `^([^,]+,){25}[^,]+$`.

Comment: thank you , the sed command is working fine for 3 delimiters but I am having issue when I am running the command on my original file , it is merging 2 records     123123,12312,12312,3453,,,,
"1231231,44",fef,sdfsd,,,,vv,   ORIGINAL  after SED  123123,12312,12312,3453,,,,"1231231,44",fef,sdfsd,,,,vv,

Comment: @Yarlly you need to update your question to include all possible scenarios.

Comment: @ Kusalananda sorry for the confusion I have updated Question

Answer (score 1):

A variation on a well-known `sed` one-liner:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n[[:blank:]]*,/,/;ta' -e 'P;D' file.csv
  ABCD,1234,QWER
  ASDF,2345,VGFT
  "ASDF,12",1212,ASDR 
  1234,ZXCV,ERTT
```